# Calling constructors of different classes that implement the same interface and are derived from same Base?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I would like know if there is a way to have a ManagerClass that calls the constructors of different classes that share the same interface and inherit form the same base class. I can not call the specific derived class constructors themselves because the user can choose which objects to create at runtime, hence I have no knowledge of which derived objects to create until runtime.

For example:

```
public class managerClass : ISomeInterface
{
   public BaseClass apply(someDataType) //(Notice return type is BaseClass) 
   {
```

> **run constructors of the derivedClasses or create essentially new derived objects, pass someDataType into the constructors**

```
   } 
}

public class derivedClass : BaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
   public void doSmthg(){manipulate data and store}
}
public class derivedClass2 : BaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
   public void doSmthg(){manipulate data in another way and store}
}
```

Currently managerClass does not inherit from same BaseClass however if this somehow helps to allow me to do what I wish to do I am not against making this change.

Comment: you want your manager class to create instances of different concrete classes depending on user input?

Comment: yes, is that possible?

Comment: Look up the Abstract Factory Pattern and see if that fits your use case.

Comment: A side note: do not pollute the hierarchy by adding the manager. Creating a separate factory is much cleaner. A manager probably does not implement the methods of the base class so it should not inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the `Activator` class:

```
Type type = typeof(derivedClass2);
ISomeInterface instance = (ISomeInterface)Activator.Create(type);
```

There are some more overloads, like passing a classname instead of a type.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx

Else you should look at `Factory Design Pattern` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem? Sure you can say:

```
public BaseClass Apply(SomeDataType someDataType)
{
  BaseClass instance;
  if (/* your condition */)
  {
    var dc = new DerivedClass();
    // do stuff to/with dc
    instance = dc;
  }
  else
  {
    var dc2 = new DerivedClass2();
    // do stuff to/with dc2
    instance = dc2;
  }
  // do common stuff to/with instance
  return instance;
}
```

Comment: I would not like to do this because then the design is not extensible, if a developer was to create another derived class they would also be required to add this 'if condition'. Currently ManagerClass stores all objects that implement ISomeInterface and calls their doSmthg methods, therefore if a developer is to create another derivedClass they only have to implement the method and inherit from BaseClass.

Comment: What is your condition? Is the user just passing the name of the implementation to be created?

Comment: @user1084113 You should edit your question to include the information that many derived classes exist, and more might need to be added later. Also you should write something about how it is to be determined _which_ derived class to use in each particular case. I might have misunderstood your question, when dealing with just `derivedClass` and `derivedClass2`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want developers to have to do is create the class and the your manager will automatically be able to create instances of it, use Reflection to gather a list of the options to present to the user, and use Activator to create the instance when requested.

```
Dictionary<string, Type> DerivedOfferings{get;set;}

... //somewhere in the setup of your manager.

foreach (Type t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEmtRequestProcessor)))))
{
    DerivedOfferings.Add(t.Name, t);
}

//provide list of options to users.
IList<string> GetOfferingOptions(){
    return DerivedOfferings.Keys.ToList();
}

...

public BaseClass GetOffering(string name){
    return (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(DerivedOfferings[type]);
}
```

If there is some logic that needs to be performed to decide which derived offering to create, you can provide an attribute for the developers to decorate their classes with which would hold information to perform the logic against.

```
public sealed class CreatureAttribute:Attribute
{
    public int NumberOfLegs{get;set;}
    public Color HairColor{get;set;}
    public int NumberOfWings{get;set;}
    public bool BreathsFire{get;set;}
}

[CreatureAttribute(NumberOfLegs=6, HairColor = Color.Magenta, NumberOfWings=0, BreathsFire=True)]
public class PurpleDragon: ICreature
{
...
}
```

Then retrieve these during enumeration and store these with the options.

```
List<CreatureCriteria> CreatureOptions{get;set;}
EnumerateOptions()
{
    foreach (Type t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICreature)))))
    {
        foreach (CreatureAttribute creatureAttribute in
                t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (CreatureAttribute), false)
                .Cast<CreatureAttribute>()                    
            {
                CreatureOptions.Add(
                    new CreatureCriteria{
                            Legs = creatureAttribute.NumberOfLegs,
                            HairColor = creatureAttribute.HairColor,
                            ...
                            ConcreteType = t
                     }
                );
            }
    }
}
```

And evaluate based on the criteria provided by the user..

```
ICreature CreateCreature(CreatureCriteria criteria){
    CreatureCriteria bestMatch = CreatureOptions.FindBestMatch(criteria);
    // perform logic comparing provided criteria against CreatureOptions to find best match.
    return (ICreature)Activator.CreateInstance(bestMatch.ConcreteType);
}
```